# Problems Popping Page with Onsen UI

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I downloaded on the Onsen UI boilerplate for a Tabbed application.  I then added a second page navigator for one of the tabs.  This second tab will have two pages available.  The problem comes when I visit this tab, go to the second page of the tab and then use popPage to go back to the first page of the tab.  After the page transition is complete, I get this:

```
Error: no such object: [object Navigator]
at Object.aliasStack.unregister (http://dev-m.scrippa.com/lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js:10848:17)
```

I'm using this method to pop:

```
<ons-button ng-click="placesNavigator.popPage()">Back</ons-button>
```

This seems like a navigator problem, but not sure what to change.  This leads me to a question:  How many navigators should an app have?  And what is breaking?

Keith

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this too.
I think you just have one navigator at the root page.